# How to solve the XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException?

Tags: xml, eclipse, maven, spring-mvc, tomcat

When I start server it shows ,

"org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException:Line 7 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 7; columnNumber: 118; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans:beans'."   in the console.

Here is my spring bean configuration xml code,

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

https://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        https://www.springframework.org/schema/beans https://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        https://www.springframework.org/schema/context https://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

```
<!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing 
    infrastructure -->

<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<annotation-driven />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.gavs.spring" />

<!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources 
    in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
<beans:bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WebContent/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>
```

Please help me out. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this error by replacing the bean configurations with this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing 
        infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.gavs.spring" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources 
        in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <bean 
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">

        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>


</beans>
```

The exception occurred due to incorrect xml tags and the configuration.